# Why am I getting AngularJS Error: $injector:modulerr Module Error

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to get a small angular app up and running but am receiving the same error every time I load my app:

```
Error: $injector:modulerr
Module Error

Failed to instantiate module app due to:
Error: [$injector:unpr] 
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.5/$injector/unpr?p0=%24scope
at https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.5/angular.min.js:7:76
at https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.5/angular.min.js:46:65
at d (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.5/angular.min.js:43:280)
at e (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.5/angular.min.js:44:6)
at Object.invoke (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.5/angular.min.js:44:91)
at d (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.5/angular.min.js:42:237)
at https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.5/angular.min.js:42:376
at p (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.5/angular.min.js:8:7)
at g (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.5/angular.min.js:42:138)
at gb (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.5/angular.min.js:46:251
```

Here is a snippet with my index.html file and my app.js file:

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.service('languageService', function($resource){

});


app.config(function($scope){
    $scope.submit = function() {
      console.log("yay");
    }
});
```

```html
<html lang="en" ng-app="app" class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title>WIT</title>
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="images/computer.ico"/>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css">
</head>
<body>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <h1><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>RecommendHer</h1>
    </div>
  </br>
  </br>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12">
        <p>Please paste job description below:</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12">
        <textarea ng-model="jobDescription"></textarea>
      </div>
    </div>
  </br>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12">
        <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="submit()">Submit</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div ng-view></div>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.5/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
  <script src="services/languageService.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Please let me know if any other information would be helpful! Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot inject $scope to config. $scope is only accessible in controller and directive. 
I think you are looking for controller?

`app.controller('yourCtrl', function($scope){ 
// your code
});`

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.service('languageService', function($resource){

});


app.config(function(){
    
});
```

```html
<html lang="en" ng-app="app" class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title>WIT</title>
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="images/computer.ico"/>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css">
</head>
<body>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <h1><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>RecommendHer</h1>
    </div>
  </br>
  </br>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12">
        <p>Please paste job description below:</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12">
        <textarea ng-model="jobDescription"></textarea>
      </div>
    </div>
  </br>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12">
        <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="submit()">Submit</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div ng-view></div>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.5/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
  <script src="services/languageService.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you need a config block? I now have my app.js file as this: var app = angular.module('app', [])

app.controller('langCtrl', function($scope){
  console.log("loaded");
    $scope.submit = function() {
      console.log("yay");
    }
}); but the submit function does not work.

Comment: no, you can remove the config block. Later in the future you may need to use config with provider.

Comment: you need to include ng-controller="langCtrl" in your html body. <body ng-controller="langCtrl">

Comment: now you may be confused why this line works:  <textarea ng-model="jobDescription"></textarea> without declaring it in langCtrl, right?

Comment: it is because angularjs will automatically add the model (jobDescription) to $scope even if you didn't declare it. But for function, you gotta declare it in the controller and include the controller in your html. For the best practice, always declare your variables/models in your controller before using